# Grunt cmd with spaces in the path

Tags: windows, gruntjs

When using `grunt.util.spawn` on win32 with spaces in the path of the `cmd` argument it is calling it without escaping the space. For instance my path contains "C:\Users\Beech Horn" so the error message I receive is

```
'C:\Users\Beech' is not a recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

However `grunt.file.exists` shows the file is there.

Also if I wrap the cmd argument with `'"' + cmd '"'`, `grunt.file.exists` can find the file however I get

```
Fatal error: spawn ENOENT
```

Has anyone solved this problem already with other grunt plugins?

Comment: The "spawn ENOENT" error seems to be a thing that happens a *lot* in node.js code (pop it into Google), mostly when the desired binary to invoke is missing.  Probably more paths-with-spaces shenanigans.  Does it work properly when all paths involved are space-free?

Comment: Good point - I am testing it through this evening to better identify the bug. Was just confused about grunt.file.exists finding it.

Comment: Adding `string.replace(' ', '\\ ')` in the right place has cleared this error but now stdin/out is not working. Time to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `cmd` variable directly, first escape spaces in the path:

`cmd.replace(' ', '\\ ')`