# Grunt can't load sass task with Spaces in path

Tags: node.js, windows, sass, gruntjs

I have a Problem with my Grunt/Sass Setup. Grunt can't find my registered Tasks because the Path has a Space in it.

When im runing `grunt --debug` I get the Error

```
[D] Task Source: C:\Users\User Name\Documents\Projects\Project\node_modules\grunt-contrib-watch\tasks\watch.js
The Command "C:\Users\User" is written wrong or could not be found.
```

Obviously grunt doesnt take the full path and only goes with  `C:\Users\User ...`
In this project I unfortunaly can't change the Location of the Project. As long as I am above the `\User Name\` grunt works just fine. Is there a Method that grunt gets to accept the path. Or is there anything I could to to escape the Space?

Thanks

Comment: Try running grunt also with ```--verbose``` flag, maybe this will provide any clues.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093349/grunt-cmd-with-spaces-in-the-path) Hopefully that points you in the direction of a fix. Though what's wrong with setting up a `C:\Dev` development directory? You're going to shortcut to it in Atom/Sublime/VS and it's easier to get to `C:\Dev` than `C:\users\foo\bar` in PowerShell.